# Bulkifying a class

Tags: apex, class, bulkification

I'm trying to process and update a bunch of claims within an occurrence.
Please guide and assist me on how to bulkify the below code. My debugs are currently returning empty. Please assist so I can use it in future:

```
public class OccurenceCalculatorTEMPORARY {

        public void calculateOcc(List<RK_Occurrence__c> myOcc)
        {
            //for(Occurence__c)
            List<Claim__c> AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence  = new List<Claim__c>();

            AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence = [Select Name, Initial_estimate__c from Claim__c where Occurrence__c =: 'myOcc'];
            system.debug(AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence);

            //set Claim Value to 0
            Decimal TotalClaimValue=0;

            For(Claim__c Item: AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence)
            {
                TotalClaimValue = TotalClaimValue + Item.Initial_estimate__c;
            }
            system.debug(TotalClaimValue);

                For(Claim__c Item: AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence)
                {
                    Item.Excess__c = (Item.Initial_estimate__c/TotalClaimValue) * Item.Policy_Excess__c;
                    Item.Captive_Stop_Loss_Estimate_Override__c = (Item.Initial_estimate__c/TotalClaimValue) * Item.Stop_Loss_Limit__c;


                }

            update AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence;            
        }
}
```

Comment: How specifically do you feel that this code is not bulkified? What problem are you trying to solve in it? Please [edit] to identify a specific problem (see [ask]) that the community can help with.

Comment: I'm trying to process and update a bunch of claims within an occurrence. So for example: if Johnny has $150 (occurrence), and Jimmy and Jack borrow $15 & $38 respectively, what is the percentage(ratio) that they have each borrowed? Then update their individual records. Hope this makes better sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulkification is usually about making the number of query calls or update calls unrelated to the number of records involved (e.g. removing a query from inside a loop). If your `calculateOcc` method is only called once, then there is no need to bulkify.

You are probably getting no records because of this:

```
... where Occurrence__c =: 'myOcc'
```

Instead, you probably need:

```
// Idiomatic code to get all the record Ids
Set<Id> occurrenceIds = new Map<Id, RK_Occurrence__c>(myOcc).keySet();
```

then:

```
... where Occurrence__c in :occurrenceIds
```

Comment: thank you so much. This set me on my way. ended up adding a map on the code.